# Code signing Error in push notification

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, code-signing-certificate

I am developing a ionic app which uses push notification. I don't have a apple developer id but working with Apple ID.It says "Cannot create a iOS App Development provisioning profile for com.xxx.xxxx". Your development team, "xxxxxxxx", does not support the Push Notifications capability.

So, I removed all the push notification packages and tried to run the app. It still displays the same message. I tried deleting all the certificated from the key chain and tried creating again. Still not able to run the app in mobile.

Comment: close the xcode and check else restart your system and check

Comment: Have you tried to disable Notifications toggle into XCode capabilities tab?

Comment: Did you try clean build?

Comment: do you have paid apple account?

Comment: Hi all, I have tried restarting Xcode and system, have disabled all the push notification capabilities... Have to try clean build. I don't have apple developer account.

Comment: As of now, I have removed all the push plugins but still the same error is there.."Cannot create a iOS App Development provisioning profile for com.xxx.xxxx". Your development team, "xxxxxxxx", does not support the Push Notifications capability.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are only available for Apple paid accounts. If you want this enroll in Apple paid program.